# React component won't render, because of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, meteor, react-bootstrap

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Panel, Input, ButtonInput} from 'react-bootstrap';

const EditItem = ({content}) => (
  <Col xs={12} sm={6} smOffset={3}>
    <Panel>
      <h1> Edit Item </h1>
      <form>
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Name of the place" />
        <Input type="textarea" placeholder="Description" />
        <ButtonInput bsStyle="primary" type="submit" value="Save Item"/>
      </form>
    </Panel>
  </Col>
);

export default EditItem;
```

I've structured all of my components in a similar fashion and they are working fine. Besides from the Input and ButtonInput imports, the component is very similar to others that are working fine. I get the followingoutput to my console:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `EditItem`.
```

Since i get three of these, i'm guessing there is one error for each Input or ButtonInput tag.

I get this message in the console as well:

```
invariant.js:39 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `EditItem`.(…)
```

I'm following a tutorial step by step, and the code in the turorial is identitcal to mine. My dependencies are all installed correctley considering that other bootstrap elements are working fine. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: which version of react-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: react-bootstrap@0.30.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version [0.30.6](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.30.6/src/index.js), there is neither `Input` nor `ButtonInput` components.

Make sure to use a version of react-bootstrap correspondong to the version used in the tutorial.

0.30.6 being the last version, you'll find all the needed documention on http://react-bootstrap.github.io/